# Run java class with command line with dependencies

Tags: java, jar, jenkins-pipeline, javac

I have a java class that uses some external lib. It runs a powershell script and does some stuff after that.
I want to run the script with Jenkinsfile, and local env via IntelliJ, so the command should be universal for Linux and Windows.
How can I execute a command line to run it?

Some things that I've tried: I have created a artifact and tried to execute it by java -jar but nothing
`java -jar ./out/artifacts/test_jar/test.jar`
I got this

```
Error: Could not find or load main class APITestRunner
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: APITestRunner
```

Also I have tried with javac but got an error
`error: package my.package does not exist`
I have a big root so whould be nice to see any -cp exapmles.
Is that doable? :D

Comment: There's no real mystery about dependencies. It's just a question of making sure they are all in the classpath. One caution: if you do `java -jar foo.jar`, you are telling java that *all* dependencies are in the jar mentioned. If you have multiple jars, you must not use `-jar` but need to use `-cp`. Your error message suggests that you made an executable jar OK, but specified your main class incorrectly

Comment: @g00se I didn't get you. How can I add all dependencies to my .jar if this is the external library? Also with -cp, I do not have a path to the library. Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: *How can I add all dependencies to my .jar if this is the external library?* You would use a so-called 'fat jar'. *Also with -cp, I do not have a path to the library* Sorry, I don't understand. Of course, you *must* have a path, and specify it

Answer (score 0):

Extract your `test.jar` and open `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` in a text editor. If there is an entry `Class-Path` in the `MANIFEST.MF` file, make sure all the dependencies listed in the `Class-Path` entry are available in the locations specified in the entry (`Class-Path` entries are relative to the location of `test.jar`).
With all dependencies in place, you should be able to run your application with `java -jar [path to test.jar]`.

If there is no `Class-Path` entry, you need to track down the dependencies of your jar in some other way. Put all those dependencies in a directory of your choice. (A `lib` subdirectory in the directory that contains the `test.jar` is usually considered a good choice.) Then run your application using

```
java -cp <classpath> <main class name>
```

E.g. suppose there are two dependencies `dep1.jar` and `dep2.jar` and the qualified class name of your main class is `com.yourcompany.Main`, then the command for Linux would be

```
java -cp test.jar:lib/dep1.jar:lib/dep2.jar com.yourcompany.Main
```

and for Windows

```
java -cp test.jar;lib\dep1.jar;lib\dep2.jar com.yourcompany.Main
```

Both examples assume that you run the `java` command in the directory that contains `test.jar`.

If you need to use the same command on Linux and Windows, you need to rebundle `test.jar` such that its `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` has a `Class-Path` entry (and a `Main-Class` entry).

Comment: Ok, " Put all those dependencies in a directory of your choice." I cannot do this cuz this is the external library. Should I download it or...?

Comment: @SeregaIlushenko What do you mean by "external library" and why does this prevent you from getting the dependencies of your java class? In any case, you cannot run a Java application without its dependencies. That is why they are called dependencies.

Comment: 1. java -cp test.jar:lib/dep1.jar:lib/dep2.jar com.yourcompany.Main , this is working, but if use 
2. java -cp test.jar:lib/*.jar com.yourcompany.Main , few dependencies are missing not sure why only few are missing. Cant we use the 2nd approach?